# MySQL - count distinct values from one column based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

i have the table resources which contains all data,
i want to get the result as given in last table..
Please help me

```
Dept Grade
A    E3  
B    M2  
D    E3  
C    M1  
A    E3  
D    E4  
A    E3
```

i used the below code but i am not able to get the actual solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department,COUNT(DISTINCT GRADE) as Grades FROM reslookup GROUP BY Department;
```

Executed Result for the about query,

```
Dept Grade
A    3
B    1
C    1
D    2
```

But, i want to get the result like given below

```
Dept E3  E4  M1  M2
A    5   0   2   1
B    4   2   3   0
C    8   9   2   1
D    5   0   2   6
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need that exact structure in MySQL and can't do it in your application layer? What's ideal from a representational relational structure is not always ideal in terms of *display*, so that's where application code comes into play.

Comment: Can you explain the desired result? from how the numbers 5, 8, 4, 6 should calculated??

Comment: How E3 column calculated 5,4,8,5 ?

Comment: @DamienSimone The numbers 5,8,4,6 is the COUNT should be taken from the Grade Column in the main table.I gave 5, 8, 4, 6 Numbers for sample only.

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy Yes, but the counts are 3,1,1,2? why 5,8,4,6 and the other values?

Comment: Yes,You are Correct..I gave for sample,in my database i have many Count so i have given like that @DamienSimone

Comment: @Shaonshaonty E3 column will be calculated by taking COUNT from the main table...i gave 5, 4, 8, 5 for sample only...

Comment: Below Query Executed Successful...thanks for the help @DamienSimone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the below code which gives the same solution

```
SELECT Dept,
      SUM(Grade = 'E3') AS E3, 
      SUM(Grade = 'E4') AS E4,
      SUM(Grade = 'M1') AS M1,
      SUM(Grade = 'M2') AS M2
    FROM reslookup 
    GROUP BY Dept;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is *pivot* rows of the counts into different columns, and this can be done as following:

```
SELECT Dept,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = 'E3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E3, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = 'E4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = 'M1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = 'M2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M2
FROM reslookup 
GROUP BY Dept;
```

[*demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ac82/2)

Comment: A shorthand will be only `SUM( Grade = 'E3')`